# Scaling centered text with CSS3 translateZ

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to scale a series of centered headlines, but the text breaks out of the container element if the window is scaled down (it's hard to describe ;) Each headline needs to stay on one line and be centered.

You can take a look at what I'm talking about here:

http://codepen.io/bobdobbalina/pen/HdBfE/?editors=110

You'll need to scale your browser window up/down to see what I mean.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: working just fine in Chrome...

Comment: What do you want to happen? If the text doesn't fit, either the container needs to be larger or the text needs to spill over...

Comment: Check out this [CSS-Tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).  Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: Does this do what you want: [forked CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hsyad?editors=110)?

Comment: @bob_dobbalina : I put my comments into an answer.  Could you accept it so that this question is more useful for future visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) post I found a CSS-only solution for scaling `font-size` to the screen size.

The solution is a new unit for `font-size`:  `vw` and `vh`.  Which are relative to the width and height of the screen.  So, I changed your definitions for the `font-size` on `h1`,`h2`:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 4vw; /* this is the vw (view width) unit in action */
}
h2 {
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 3vw; /* this is the vw (view width) unit in action */
}
```

Here's a [forked CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hsyad?editors=110) showing the effect with that solution with the text scaling relative to the width of the browser.

(Note that this is not supported by all browsers, so a JS backup plan might be good.)

Answer (score 1):

**not too sure of what you are trying**, but if you want your text to be centered and overflowing on both sides, your `h2` should have no virtual width and display should be turned to `inline-block`.

test this http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/cAyit

In this case , `transform` has nothing to do here :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'white-space: pre' this from your css

'pre' preserves New lines, Spaces and tabs

```
h1 {
  white-space: pre;
}

h2 {
  white-space: pre;
}
```